# Must Riverpod notify listeners who are constructed in LayoutBuilders?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

If I have a parent and child built like this:

```
class Parent extends ConsumerWidget {
  build(...) {
    ref.watch(myProvider);
    return Child();
  }
}

class Child extends ConsumerWidget {
  build(...) {
    ref.watch(myProvider);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

when `myProvider` notifies, only `Parent` is rebuilt.  The `Child` instance is not.  This makes sense: the `Child` instance is about to be replaced by a new one from `Parent.build()`, so it won't be in the widget tree anymore and shouldn't be rebuilt.

If I change `Parent` to use `LayoutBuilder`, like

```
class Parent extends ConsumerWidget {
  build(...) {
    ref.watch(myProvider);
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (_, __) => Child());
  }
}
```

then something different happens: both `Parent` and the **original** `Child` are rebuilt, followed by the `LayoutBuilder` constructing and build()ing a **new** `Child`.

This was a surprise to me: I didn't want my first `Child` to be rebuilt, because it wasn't going to be in the widget tree.  But I realize that Riverpod can't tell before layout whether the first `Child` will be returned by `LayoutBuilder.builder`, so I guess it takes the "safe" approach and rebuilds it. *(Of course, in this toy example, `Child` has no need to watch the provider, but in a real app it may not know whether its parent plans to reuse or construct a new instance.)*

**This seems smart, but users won't always want Riverpod to notify `Child`.**  In my case, `Child` uses a GlobalKey, and building the old and new `Child` instances caused an error saying there are two GlobalKeys in the same widget tree.

Is this a Riverpod bug or intended behavior, and what's the cleanest workaround?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I doubt this has anything to do with Riverpod. Rather it sounds like a specificity of `LayoutBuilder` and the fact that you're changing the shape of your widget tree.

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with GlobalKeys though. It could be a Flutter bug or a limitation of LayoutBuilder.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks, I was just writing commit notes and came to the same conclusion.  Riverpod is just rebuilding whoever is in the tree.